# How to detect if file exists in Google Drive (and not trashed) using Java?

Tags: java, google-drive-api

Pretty self-explanatory title. I'm using Google Drive Client Api for Java. What I currently have is as follows:

```
File f = mService.files.get(fileId).execute();
```

However, I can't find the property in `File` used to check if a file is trashed or not. `File.getExplicitlyTrashed()` gives me null for both trashed and not trashed files.

Answer (score 3):

The `trashed` property is hidden inside the [`File.Labels`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/model/File.Labels.html) class, which you can get from [`File.getLabels()`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/model/File.html#getLabels()). A working example is:

```
public boolean validFileId(String id) {
    try {
        File f = mService.files().get(id).execute();
        return !f.getLabels().getTrashed();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("bad id: " + id);
    }
    return false;
}
```