# existing file in subfolder google drive

Tags: vb.net, file, google-drive-api, exists

I want to verify if file exist or not in google drive with vb.net , the file path is in subfolder . I create existfile method where i list subfolder and list file and use a test , but always countfile=0 .
This is existfile method code

```
 Public Function existfile(v As String) As String
    Dim page As String = ""
    Dim req = Service.Files.List()
    req.Q = "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.file' and trashed = false "
    req.Spaces = "drive"
    req.Fields = "nextPageToken, items(id, title)"
    req.PageToken = page
    Dim result = req.Execute()
    ' sous doc
    Dim ref = Service.Files.List()
    ref.Q = "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed = false "
    Dim fo = ref.Execute()

    'récuprer la reference (ID) du dossier existant , sinon la fonction retourne false en cas d'inexistance'
    Const a As String = "false"
    For Each listf In fo.Items
        For Each test In result.Items
            If (test.Title = v) Then
                Return (test.Id)
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return (a)
End Function
```

the first for each is for list folder , and the second is for list file already exist , but result.item is always 0

the file path is under subfolder , and the subfolder is under the bigfolder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check this [.NET Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet) which uses [`Files.List`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) to list the file on your Google Drive.

```
// Define parameters of request.
FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
listRequest.PageSize = 10;
listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";

// List files.
IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute()
        .Files;
Console.WriteLine("Files:");
if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", file.Name, file.Id);
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No files found.");
}
Console.Read();
```

Additional reference: [Google Drive API - Check if file exists by file ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39665269/google-drive-api-check-if-file-exists-by-file-id)

Comment: Thank you , Your code search a file in google drive not in folder or subfolder (I mean always the result is No files found ) .
I found a solution , i used 2 foreach , the first for list all folder exist in drive , and the next for list all files exist in folders , then i used a if test , the result it work correctly .