# How to ask Google Drive if a file exists by name with google drive api

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

If I just box `Files.List` in a `try-catch` block like I've seen in other answers (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39665269/google-drive-api-check-if-file-exists-by-file-id)), search by name and the file doesn't exist, I just catch an exception with `File not found` 404 error in the exception message.

I don't think the only way to know if a file exists or not is doing something like `Contains("404")` on a catched exception message... Is it?

I've searched on google and here, and I can't find anything apart from "use `Files.List()`".

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You want to confirm whether the file is existing in Google Drive using the filename.

If my understanding is correct, how about this method?

When a file is searched by the filename, you can use search query `q` of the files.list method in Drive API. In your case, you can use `q=name='fileName'`. When the files.list method is requested using `q=name='fileName'`, if the file with the filename of `fileName` was not found, the property of `files` of the response has the empty array like `{"files": []}`. By this, I confirm the existence of the file.

The endpoint and sample script are as follows.

#### Endpoint:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=name%3D'fileName'
```

#### Sample script:

```
FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
listRequest.Q = "name='fileName'";
var files = listRequest.Execute();
```

#### Note:

- If you don't want to search in the trash box, please add `trashed=false` to `q` like `name='fileName' and trashed=false`.

#### References:

- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters)
- [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/dotnet)

If this was not what you want, I apologize.

Comment: :P No need to apologyze. Going to test this today again, but the thing yesterday was that it wasn't returning an empty array, just a 404 exception with the message `File not found`. You can confirm to me that the standard response is an empty array? Maybe I was missing something after all.

Comment: @Nox Thank you for replying. And I'm sorry for the inconvenience. For example, as a confirmation, when you use "Try this API" at [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list?apix_params=%7B%22q%22%3A%22name%3D%27fileName%27%22%7D), when you use ``name='fileName'`` as no filename in your Drive, can you retrieve the result of ``"files": []``?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it and it works as intended. Seems that I failed somewhere. Maybe the parent were wrong... oops. Well, at least it's a confirmation, next time I'll search my own error. Thanks!

Comment: @Nox Thank you for testing it.

Comment: Hello, I am trying to do same but it's throwing Bad Request error 
Query is "name='leaf-pic.jpg'"

And error message is

Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError

Invalid query [400]

Errors [

 Message[Invalid query] Location[q - parameter] Reason[invalid] Domain[global]

]

Comment: how do I do this if I have fileId ?